# Multiple template reference variable in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In one of my component's template input element I have created two different reference variables, something like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="..." #typeAhead="ngbTypeahead"
       #relationTypeInput>
```

**P.S: This is not the exact code, but my actual code is similar to this one**

In the component ts file these variable are declared as follows:

```
@ViewChild('typeAhead') typeAhead: NgbTypeahead;
@ViewChild('relationTypeInput') relationTypeInput: ElementRef;
```

Then I am using the former one in ngOnInit() and the later one in ngAfterViewInit(). To my surprise I didn't got any error and it's working, but I don't understand how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `#typeAhead` isn't a reference to the element, in this case the `input`. This is why it's defined when `ngOnInit` runs, while `#relationTypeInput` is not.

Comment: Thanks for your ans @Chrillewoodz, can you please also explain why #typeAhead is not a reference here? Is it because it's of type NgbTypeahead?

Comment: @BijaySingh I assume that `NgbTypeahead` is a directive so it's a reference to the directive itself rather than the input element.

Answer (score 2):

In the later versions of Angular (v10+) you would need to use `ngAfterViewInit`

Up to v7, Angular stated that `ngOnInit` was not a reliable lifecycle hook from which to reference `ViewChild` properties, but it was common knowledge that it was reliable. In v8/9, you need to add an option `{static: true}` to the `ViewChild` to allow the property to be referenced in `ngOnInit` - but this had other affects on the property (e.g. it would never update after that point)

You can read more about it here https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration